# Gradle extra property does not exist - defined in sub-module

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I'm migrating maven build to gradle and I'm struggling with defining basic plugin configuration in the root project. And providing specific configuration properties in sub-module.

Here is an example:

root: build.gradle

```
configure(filterSubprojects(['component'])) {

    apply plugin: "org.flywaydb.flyway"

    flyway {
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.name}"
        user = db.owner.name
        password = db.owner.password
    }

}
```

specific-subproject-component: build.gradle

```
ext {
    db = [
            host          : <host>,
            port          : <port>,
            name          : <name>,
            user          : [name: <user-name>, password: <user-password>]
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot get property 'db' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

Probably very basic question, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is, that the specifics component build.gradle file was not yet evaluated when your root build.gradle file is evaluated, so db does indeed not yet exist when the configure block runs. To fix this you should be able to declare `evaluationDependsOnChildren()` in your root build.gradle file.